# Which format support the audio file with a playing video?

Tags: iphone, video, audio, mp3, mp4

i am playing the video and in the background i have to play the audio file and if i do this audio is not playing its sound as it just play video is it a extension problem i am using the .mp3 for the audio and .mp4 for the video .

how can we do this we have to play simultanisouly .both the file 
balraj verma

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this:
http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/MusicAudio/Conceptual/CoreAudioOverview/CoreAudioEssentials/CoreAudioEssentials.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40003577-CH10-SW67

"To play multiple sounds simultaneously, create one playback audio queue object for each sound. For each audio queue, schedule the first buffer of audio to start at the same time using the AudioQueueEnqueueBufferWithParameters function.

Audio format is critical when you play sounds simultaneously on iPhone or iPod touch. This is because playback of certain compressed formats in iPhone OS employs an efficient hardware codec. Only a single instance of one of the following formats can play on the device at a time:

AAC
ALAC (Apple Lossless)
MP3"