# How to play audio and video together in iphone

Tags: iphone, video, audio

I want to play some videos with audio from different audio files. For this i am playing a video(using MPMoviePlayerController) and i am playing an audio(using AVAudioPlayer).

When i play my code through simulator it works fine (the video with my audio file specified). When i run the application in device it doesn't work like that. It plays video but sound file is not getting played. How can i play an audio and a video together ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has been discussed before and I don't think anyone's figured it out yet:

[Play audio and video at a same time in iPhone application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1376909/play-audio-and-video-at-a-same-time-in-iphone-application)
[how can we play audio and video together in ipod/iphone?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1201815/how-can-we-play-audio-and-video-together-in-ipod-iphone)
[Which format support the audio file with a playing video?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1106992/which-format-support-the-audio-file-with-a-playing-video)